# how can i Set maximum and minimum length in number_field in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<label class="control-label">count</label>
<%= f.number_field :count, {:placeholder => "Count", :class => "multiple_text_field form-control", :required => true, :max=>"8",:min=>"8" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have exactly 8 digits, the `min` value would be `10000000` and the `max` value would be `99999999`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have done it almost. A little change to this:

```
<%= f.number_field :count, {:placeholder => "Count", :class => "multiple_text_field form-control", :required => true, max: 8, min: 8 } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.number_field :count, max: 10, min:4 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", title: "Enter title length 50 characters", placeholder: "Enter Title", :required => true,:maxlength => 50, pattern: ".{1,50}"  %>
```